# How to Create Same resource Twice in Puppet

Tags: puppet

My requirement is to do some repetitive file configuration stuff using a loop, Something like following,

```
$no_of_managers = 2
$array = ['One','two','Three']


define loop() {

notice("Configuring The Manager Nodes!!")

if ($name == $no_of_managers+1) {
    notice("Loop Iteration Finished!!!")
  }
  else
  {
    notice("Iteration Number : $name \n")

    # Doing All Stuff Here 

resource {$array:}

    $next = $name + 1
    loop { $next: }
 }
 }

loop { "1":}

define resource () {
# Doing my other Stuff
notice ("The Parsed value Name : ${name}\n")

}
```

Now when The second iteration is running the following error occurs,

```
Error: Duplicate declaration: Resource[One] is already declared in file
```

How can I overcome this, What I'm doing is a cluster setup. Is there a workaround to do this, I'm a newbie for puppet so Your kind guidance highly appreciated.

The Use Case :

I'm trying to setup a cluster which have multiple Manager/Worker nodes, So using this script the user has the privilege to select how many manager nodes he needs. So the first loop is for that to copy necessary files and create required number of nodes.

The second loop is there to push all .erb templates. Because each Node has slightly different configs the .erb files have there own logic inside them.

So after each Iteration I want to push the .erb templates to the respective node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Puppet 3.x, you cannot build a loop in the fashion you are trying.

```
resource { $array: }
```

**is** a loop over the contents of `$array` if you will.

It is not really clear what you are trying to solve. If you can make your question a bit more concrete, we may be able to suggest an actual implementation.

#### Update

If you really want to go down this road, you need to generate unique names for your derived resources.

```
$local_names = regsubst($array, '$', "-$name")

resource { $local_names: }
```

In your defined type, you will have to retrieve the original meaning by removing the suffix.

```
define resource() {
    $orig_name = regsubst($name, '-[0-9]+$', '')
    # use $orig_name where you used $name before
}
```

Note that even exported resources must have unique names. So the transformation may have to happen on in the manifest of the receiving node.

Comment: Hi I have edited the question, The loop works perfectly. I have Puppet 3.6.2. Yes the second loop is over the array.

Comment: I see. Strictly speaking you just built a recursive define ;) I'll update my answer.